# Does shaking a kettle whilst boiling increase the temperature faster than a statically-placed jug?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, water

Water molecules move faster at higher temperatures.

- Does shaking a boiling kettle whilst it is in the process of boiling water increase the rate of rising temperature ?
- Is it worthwhile to do so to save time ?

It's dangerous, so I wouldn't try it myself.

Comment: Shaking the kettle by sliding it back and forth on the burner increases the rate of convective heat transfer.   This should help a little.

Comment: However, whilst natural convection always displaces cold water with hot water, manually-induced convection does not necessarily. It will randomly displace water, and so there is a chance that any natural convection will be "sent back" by the shaking.

Comment: "and so there is a chance that any natural convection will be "sent back" by the shaking". Not true. Agitation, including shaking and stirring, causes also mixing. This means the 'cold' temperature at the 'hot/cold' interface is always as low as possible. As per Newton's heating/cooling Law that promotes heat transfer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, agitation will generally promote heat transfer and reduce heating times (although *quantifying* the effect is not easy). But the effect is *not related* to the bulk speed of the kettle.

[image: Boundary layer.]

When the water is heated a diffuse (poorly defined) boundary layer is formed on the bottom of the vessel. This layer is at a temperature that is slightly higher than the bulk of the water above it.

This limits the transfer of heat from the heated surface somewhat, acc. Newton's Law of Heating/Cooling:

$$\frac{dQ}{dt}=kA(T_{hot}-T_{boundary}),$$

where $\frac{dQ}{dt}$ is the amount of heat ($\mathrm{Watt}$) transferred from the hot surface to the boundary layer *per unit of time*, $k$ a heat transfer coefficient, $A$ the surface area of contact, $T_{hot}$ the temperature of the bottom of the vessel and $T_{boundary}$ the temperature of the boundary layer.

But agitating effectively has the effect of reducing the boundary layer's *thickness* and through homogenisation probably also its temperature. The first effect actually means we're *increasing* the value of $k$, the effect of which on $\frac{dQ}{dt}$ is straight forward. And increased $\frac{dQ}{dt}$ lowers overall heating times.

For slightly reduced heating times, all other things being equal, stirring/shaking/agitation is beneficial (but the effect is difficult to *quantitatively* model).

---

In fluid mechanics the thickness of a boundary layer is correlated to the [Reynolds number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_number):

$$Re=\frac{vL}{\eta}$$

where $v$ is the fluid speed, $L$ is a characteristic length (like the diameter of the kettle) and $\eta$ the viscosity of the fluid. Increasing Reynolds numbers (increased fluid speed $v$, e.g.) reduces boundary layer thickness and promotes heat transfer.

As the boundary layer is essentially stationary, heat transfer across the boundary layer is essentially by conduction (Fourrier's Law}:

$$\frac{dQ}{dt} \approx \kappa A\frac{\Delta T}{\Delta x}$$

where $\Delta T$ is the temperature difference across the boundary layer, $\kappa$ the heat conductivity of water and $\Delta x$ the thickness of the boundary layer. The smaller $\Delta x$, the higher $\frac{dQ}{dt}$.

Answer (score 1):

Coherent motion does not add to the temperature; so you would have to shake it violently, with random motions.

Consider sound in air - this is a coherent motion - when you can no longer make out the sounds in a closed room, the energy of the sound waves has been transformed into heat.